# How to revert to the last libc without the .annobin.notes section?

Tags: linux, fedora, downgrade, glibc

I am working with Intel Pin, and after a system upgrade, I realized it does not work with binaries that have the section `.annobin.notes` which apparently has been introduced by the people at Red Hat (I am using Fedora).

After some back and forth with people in change of Pin, they say they may add support for future versions. But now I have a system where libc (therefore, pretty much every application) has the `.annobin.notes` section, so I cannot use the tool.

Before the system upgrade, everything was fine. The problem is that I don't know what version of libc I had back then. So my question is two fold:

1. What is (or how to identify) the last version of libc without such section?
2. How can I downgrade my system to use such version of libc?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't downgrade as you will just introduce other errors possibly bricking the install. Instead fire up a vm and run an old version within it.

Comment: that is not an option. I am measuring system performance, and a vm would ruin all measurements.

Comment: then you need to downgrade the entire system, not just libc.